# New 2.5 hp outboard motor has reduced power at full throttle

Tags: power, throttle, boat, outboard

I have a new [2.5 hp 4-stroke Mercury outboard motor](https://www.mercurymarine.com/en/ca/engines/outboard/fourstroke/25-25hp/) on a [12-foot aluminum boat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpS3T.png):

[image]

I've used the motor four times; 15 km per trip.

When I first got the motor, it seemed to have a lot more power at full throttle. Now, there seems to be significantly less power.

I  don't think the difference in power is all in my head: Previously, at full power/throttle, the motor only got about 1 km to a tank (the tank is small and built into the motor). Now, at full throttle, there is less power, and I can get 10+ km to a single tank on full throttle. So the fact that I now get 10x fuel range at full throttle is evidence that it's not operating at full power.

Notes:

1. The motor has oil in it.
2. I use supreme-quality gas.
3. The weight in the boat hasn't changed and the conditions haven't changed -- I only boat on calm water, on the same lake in the same place, with minimal gear.
4. The motor's shaft is tilted so that it's perpendicular to the water (straight up and down when in operation). I believe that's the correct angle.
5. When initially breaking in the new motor, I followed the manufacturer's instructions (reduced throttling for specific durations).
6. Here's a photo of the spark plug condition (click to zoom in):
   [image]

As a novice, I'm wondering why I no longer have full power/speed at full throttle.

Comment: Have you pulled the spark plug and examined it for fouling? There should be no black or oily residue on the electrode, in the spark gap or on the insulator, just a very light coating of a tan, dust-like material, or it could still be perfectly clean considering its age. Learn to read spark plugs as a diagnostic procedure. https://ngksparkplugs.com/en/resources/read-spark-plug

Comment: I have a feeling, reading the plug, you're going to find the engine is running lean, which is why you have reduced power at WOT and you're getting better fuel mileage overall.

Comment: Does it have a fuel filter?

Comment: @MTA I updated the question with a photo of the sparkplug. What do you think?

Comment: @User1974 - If anything, it looks like it's running a tad rich. If it were running well, it'd have a tan color to it. If it was running lean, it would be white to a lighter tan color. Don't know what's going on from your description and these photos.

Comment: @GdD I'm a novice, so I don't know if it has a fuel filter or not. I don't see any mention of a fuel filter in the manual. I'll need to get someone more experienced than me to take a look at the motor and tell me if it has a fuel filter.

Comment: I agree with Paulster2 about the plug. You can download a manual from Mercury to find out about the fuel filter. I don't imagine you've done much maintenance yet, but if this motor has an oil-impregnated air filter and you've over-oiled it, that could cause it to run rich. Manual download here: https://www.mercurymarine.com/en/ca/land/owners-manuals/

Comment: If you just bought this it should be under warranty. It sounds to me like you've done everything right, so it should be running fine. As it's having problems Mercury should fix it.

Comment: @GdD I called up the dealer I bought it from. They wondered if it might be bad gas or a bit of debris in the gas that clogged something up. Will bring the motor into them to get it checked out when I get a chance. The guy didn't know if the motor has a fuel filter or not.

Comment: @GdD I called the manufacturer. They say no, the motor doesn't have a fuel filter.